# Nestjs | ConfigModule | Use (or inject) a service inside `validate` function

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nestjs-config

```
import { validate } from './env.validation';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validate,
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I use some service from within `validate` function? For example a `Logger` service?
Can a service be injected into `validate`?

Comment: from where did `ConfigModule` came?

Comment: @Micael Levi: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

Comment: Hey @fmagno Please share an answer if you find a solution. I need the exact same thing right now.

Answer (score 1):

as you could see in it source code [here](https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/2d3fc708eee8b38f7d27ec562011bbd3cc831e0e/lib/config.module.ts#L49-L50) there is no way to inject providers in this `validate` function because it is just a conventional callback that doesn't know about the Nest DI system.

Comment: I'm trying to use as much as possible the nestjs ConfigModule, its validation mechanisms and its services but to also be able to use other custom services across the board. Do you have a suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Comment: It's still not clear to me how one can effectively use the ConfigModule and be able to, for example, log a message when something goes wrong during the  validation call.

Comment: that lib will thrown an error when the validation fails, and the app will not start. See https://github.com/nestjs/config/blob/2d3fc708eee8b38f7d27ec562011bbd3cc831e0e/tests/e2e/validate-function.spec.ts#L17 maybe you can use that error somehow to do what you want to, or build your own `ConfigModule` :/

Answer (score 1):

### Heading

In your case, I would build a class to implement `ValidatorConstraintInterface`, which is from class-validator. Then, you can use the answer from this issue to inject dependencies:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/528

TL:DR
use this on your bootstrap() and implement the ValidatorConstraintInterface, so you can inject dependencies:

`useContainer(app.select(AppModule), {fallbackOnErrors: true});`

Comment: How you pass the `validate` method, of your suggested new service, to the ConfigModule.forRoot({ validate })?